# how to mount a share path for the big dataset in windows os for computer vision annotation tool cvat while building a docker container for it?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, computer-vision, data-annotations, object-detection

I am sorry for a noob question but I want to know how to mount a shared path for the big dataset. I tried to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/opencv/cvat/blob/master/cvat/apps/documentation/installation.md#share-path) on the Share Path

```
version: "2.3"

services:
  cvat:
    environment:
      CVAT_SHARE_URL: "Mounted from /mnt/share host directory"
    volumes:
      - cvat_share:/home/django/share:ro

volumes:
  cvat_share:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /mnt/share
      o: bind
```

but I am getting this error while building

```
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.override.yml -f components/openvino/docker-compose.openvino.yml -f cvat/apps/dextr_segm
entation/docker-compose.dextr.yml  -f components/auto_segmentation/docker-compose.auto_segmentation.yml -f components/tf_annotation/docker-compo
se.tf_annotation.yml -f components/analytics/docker-compose.analytics.yml up -d

WARNING: The no_proxy variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The http_proxy variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
WARNING: The https_proxy variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string.
cvat_redis is up-to-date
cvat_db is up-to-date
cvat_elasticsearch is up-to-date
cvat_kibana is up-to-date
cvat_logstash is up-to-date
Creating cvat ... error                                                                                                                          
ERROR: for cvat  Cannot create container for service cvat: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/share:/var/lib/docker/volumes/cvat_cvat_share/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory

ERROR: for cvat  Cannot create container for service cvat: failed to mount local volume: mount /mnt/share:/var/lib/docker/volumes/cvat_cvat_share/_data, flags: 0x1000: no such file or directory
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

```
$ Docker version
Client: Docker Engine - Community
Version: 19.03.8
API version: 1.40
Go version: go1.12.17
Git commit: afacb8b
Built: Wed Mar 11 01:23:10 2020
OS/Arch: windows/amd64
Experimental: true
```

**what procedure do I need to follow to work this out? Please help me.**

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose file, you are creating the `cvat_share` volume with device `/mnt/share`. The device should be an existing path on the host OS (in this case Windows), but `/mnt/share` doesn't look like a valid Windows path (it has no drive letter).

You should check the folder (on the Windows host) in which your shared files are and try changing the device path (e.g. if the folder path is `C:\path\to\share`, the device path should be `/C/path/to/share`):

```yaml
volumes:
  cvat_share:
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      device: /C/path/to/share
      o: bind
```

Don't forget to change the `CVAT_SHARE_URL` accordingly for having the correct message in the application.